# Techniques for Hybrid Fixed Position HTML Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

Let's say a designer wishes to have:

- a fixed navigation element divide a left and right content area (no scrollbar for left area)
- a non-collapsable right content area (e.g. cannot prevent against horizontal scrollbar for small viewports)

This presents a dilemma where the content will scroll under the fixed position navigation bar during the presence of a horizontal scrollbar.  While this design is uncommon, the only solutions that come to mind involve JavaScript scroll event listeners.

My first two stabs at this were:

1) nudge the fixed position elements over via scrollX's value to make them "hybrid-fixed" (fixed vertically, but movable horizontally via JavaScript)

2) set the left area as `position:fixed` with `overflow-y: hidden` and emulate scrolling in JavaScript to mimic the main scrollbar by adjusting `margin-top`

Check out [this jFiddle for a live example of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/camerican/2mykk41g/) and the aforementioned JavaScript solutions.  In the Fiddle, click the link *"scroll under the fixed position nav bar"* to see the problem and click the buttons to apply JavaScript solutions.

Any alternate approaches (especially non-JS techniques), would be welcome.